# Array issues with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like

```
var arr = [3,6,9,10];
```

It needs to proceed with this logic and get the sum :

```
3*6 = 18;
6*9 = 54;
9*10 = 90;

sum = 162;
```

how can I achieve this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    sum = arr[i]*arr[i+1]; 
}
```

doesn't return me the sum I want.

Comment: Can you post the code you're currently trying, with an explanation of what works and what does not.

Comment: This reeks of "do my homework for me please"

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 sum = arr[i]*arr[i+1];
} it doesnt return me the sum i want

Comment: add sum+= instead of sum=

Comment: You additionally had to restrict your upper limit to arr.length-1. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

```
var arr = [3,6,9,10];
var sum = 0;
for (var i =0; i<arr.length-1; i++)
{
    sum += arr[i]*arr[i+1];
}

alert(sum);
```

It deliviers 162.